# Applications are not using the same keyboard mappings, it seems

Tags: centos, keyboard-layout

I’m using an american keyboard and writing in Portuguese. I updated `/etc/sysconfig/keyboard` as the following [article](http://www.metod.si/change-keyboard-layout-in-centos-in-console/) suggested. It worked but only in the console. Firefox and Sublime Text2 shows **'+c** (ç) as **ć**, gedit shows nothing.
In Firefox and Sublime Text2 the only problem is **ç**, gedit is quite different, it seems like a Brazilian ABNT2 keyboard.

**OS: CentOS 6**

Contents of locale:

```
LANG=pt_BR.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE=”pt_BR.UTF-8″
LC_NUMERIC=”pt_BR.UTF-8″
LC_TIME=”pt_BR.UTF-8″
LC_COLLATE=”pt_BR.UTF-8″
LC_MONETARY=”pt_BR.UTF-8″
LC_MESSAGES=”pt_BR.UTF-8″
LC_PAPER=”pt_BR.UTF-8″
LC_NAME=”pt_BR.UTF-8″
LC_ADDRESS=”pt_BR.UTF-8″
LC_TELEPHONE=”pt_BR.UTF-8″
LC_MEASUREMENT=”pt_BR.UTF-8″
LC_IDENTIFICATION=”pt_BR.UTF-8″
LC_ALL=
```

contents of `/etc/sysconfig/keyboard`

```
KEYTABLE=”br-latin1-us”
MODEL=”latin1-us”
LAYOUT=”br”
KEYBOARDTYPE=”pc”
```